# How do I add opening and closing brackets to the beginning and end of the data string in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a column of text in sqlite that I have to select and add brackets to the beginning and end of each string of data.  EG. column has "hello"  I need to select it, adding brackets so it looks like "(hello)"

I have done this before in Sqlite, but can't remember how I did it. Any ideas would be really appreciated.  I am sure it will be  pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

Use `||` to concatenate strings:

```
SELECT '(' || 'hello' || ')';

SELECT '(' || column_name || ')' FROM table_name WHERE condition;
```

Comment: Thanks that was just what I needed, worked beautifully and the project is now done. I appreciate the help!